# How to read <image> tag containing Title, Image and url from rss feed

Tags: android, xml-parsing, rss

I was able to get all data inside item tag i.e Title, Link, Description, Image and PublishedDate, below is my XMLParser class

```
        if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

            if (xmlPullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {

                insideItem = true;

            } else if (xmlPullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {

                if (insideItem) {
                    String title = xmlPullParser.nextText();
                    currentArticle.setTitle(title);
                }

            } else if (xmlPullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {

                if (insideItem) {
                    String link = xmlPullParser.nextText();
                    currentArticle.setLink(link);
                }

            } else if (xmlPullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {

                if (insideItem) {
                    String description = xmlPullParser.nextText();
                    currentArticle.setDescription(description);
                }

            }  else if (xmlPullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("media:thumbnail")) {

                if (insideItem) {
                    String htmlData = xmlPullParser.nextText();
                    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlData);
                    try {
                        //Get image url from media:content tag
                        String pic = xmlPullParser.getAttributeValue(null, "url");
                        currentArticle.setImage(pic);
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        currentArticle.setImage(null);
                    }
                    currentArticle.setContent(htmlData);
                }

            } else if (xmlPullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {

                if (insideItem) {
                    String description = xmlPullParser.nextText();
                    currentArticle.setDescription(description);
                }

            } else if (xmlPullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate")) {
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                Date pubDate = new Date(xmlPullParser.
                        nextText());

                currentArticle.setPubDate(pubDate);
            }

        }
            else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xmlPullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
            insideItem = false;
            insideChannel = false;
            articles.add(currentArticle);
            currentArticle = new Article();
        }
        eventType = xmlPullParser.next();
```

My problem is how I can read data inside item tag and image tag. I know i must have correct my condition statement, tried a lot but i couldn't find out any solution

```
 <image>
        <url>http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/nol/shared/img/bbc_news_120x60.gif</url>
        <title>BBC News - World</title>
        <link>http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/</link>
 </image>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three way to parse XML file. Parsing XML file using DOM Parser is easy but it is slower then other parser, So XMLPullParser is better then DOM and you have to parse different way with every parser.

You will get the solution of you problem in below link.

https://www.journaldev.com/10653/android-xml-parser-xmlpullparser